# How to fix skip to content option in magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, error, permissions, static-content

I have issue with the magento2. When we open a website the skip to content appear before loading the complete website . How i remove this option. Image is atatched.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your themes default.xml file

```
<referenceBlock name="skip_to_content" remove="true"/>
```